# Change the key that show previous command lines in ksh

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh, command-history

In most shells on Linux, when you press the <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> key, it shows the previous command lines from the command line history.

My question is, for the `ksh` shell,

1. How do I set up some other key so that it shows previous command line?
2. How do I *disable* the <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> key so that it doesn't show the previous command line?

Comment: You might have to look at `cat /etc/inputrc`

Comment: Many shells provide command line history with the aid of the [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html) library.  To find which shell you are using, run `echo $0` -- then edit your question to include the output.

Comment: OK, you're using the korn shell.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623256/make-arrow-and-delete-keys-work-in-kornshell-command-line .

Comment: ksh? That brings back memories! It used to be my favourite shell (or certainly I don't remember using any shell as much). Like say in the 1990s. That was mostly under SunOS/Solaris. I didn't know people still used ksh (even though I did look at it a few years ago out of curiosity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most tutorials you can find are about bash. Ksh is very good at scripting but is bad at interactive use. Use zsh (best) or bash (second-best) as a command line if you can.

There are two main implementations of ksh today: the actual Korn shell ksh93, and the clone mksh (derived from the long-unmaintained pdksh). They have different key binding facilities.

In ksh93, the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys don't move in the command line history by default. The default keys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. You can change key bindings via the `KEYBD` trap; it's rather clumsy as you can only translate keys to other keys and all the bindings have to be defined in the same place. Here's how to make <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> navigate the history (this code goes into `~/.kshrc`):

```
set -o emacs
function KEYBD_trap {
  case ${.sh.edchar} in
    $'\e'[[O]A) .sh.edchar=$'\e>';;
    $'\e'[[O]B) .sh.edchar=$'\e<';;
  esac
}
trap KEYBD_trap KEYBD
```

`\e[A` and `\eOA`, where `\e` stands for the [ASCII escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character), are the two escape sequences that the terminal may send when the user presses the <kbd>Up</kbd> key (it depends on the terminal and on its current mode). Likewise `\e[B` and `\eOB` is for <kbd>Down</kbd>. `$'\e` is a notation you can use in ksh for the escape character; the pattern `[[O]` matches either a `[` or a `O`.

In mksh, you define key bindings via the `bind` builtin. <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> navigate the history by default (in addition to kbd>Ctrl+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>). The following code (to be put in `~/.mkshrc`) disables the arrow keys:

```
bind '^[OA'=
bind '^[[A'=
bind '^[OB'=
bind '^[[B'=
```

`^[` is a notation you can use in mskh key bindings for the escape character.

All this information is in the man page of the shell, not necessarily in a form that's comprehensible if you aren't familiar with Unix shells already.

Comment: (opinions) For interactive use, I find that shells, like `bash` and `zsh`, that tries too hard to second-guess my behaviour (and gets it wrong), or have too many bells-and-whistles, are more a hinderance than a help. `ksh` is brutally honest with me, like a good friend ;-)

Comment: I seem to only need to use the `set -o emacs` line in .kshrc with version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01